# Counting and ordering unique values in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to a find/create a function that can take one vector and return a vector of the same length that "counts" the # instance of that value. e.g.:

For input:

```
a <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 4)
```

I'd like the output:

```
1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3,3,4,5
```

I've built a for-loop that works just fine, but takes excruciating long when I actually try to apply it to my dataset (~100,000 rows, not even that large!).
I also found `rleid` from `data.table` which comes close, but still isn't quite right.

Answer (score 3):

In base R you could use

```
ave(a, a, FUN = seq_along)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 1 2 3 3 4 5
```

From `data.table` use `rowid`

```
data.table::rowid(a)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 1 2 3 3 4 5
```

**benchmark**

```
set.seed(1)
aa <- sample(1:10, 1e6, TRUE)

library(microbenchmark)
benchmark <- microbenchmark(
  baseR = ave(aa, aa, FUN = seq_along),
  data.table = rowid(aa)
)

autoplot(benchmark)
```

[image]

```
benchmark
#Unit: milliseconds
#       expr       min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#      baseR 51.161437 52.672874 55.75084 53.81096 57.66393 80.09238   100   b
# data.table  9.242893  9.811798 13.30292 10.47203 12.12332 36.88062   100  a
```